# Sending protoplasm datetimepicker info. to different div

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker

I'm trying to implement a [Protoplasm datetimepicker](http://jongsma.org/software/protoplasm/control/datepicker) widget I'd like to display the selected date/time in a div in a nice format, but then transmit the date/time to MySQL when I submit a form.  Protoplasm seems to rely fully on its internal javascript files, so I don't really have any code to display.  This is all I've really got code-wise...

```
<input type="text" name="date" size="25px" class="datetimepicker" />
```

Can anyone with Protoplasm experience help here?  Thanks!